# Git workflow: Merge existing branch to new branch and delete old one

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Scenario:
being on master branch

1. git checkout ***target_branch***
2. git checkout ***new_branch***
3. git commit -m: "TARGET BRANCH TASK NUMBER,NEW BRANCH TASK NUMBER: Message"
4. git push origin ***new_branch***
5. git checkout ***target_branch***
6. git push origin ***target_branch***

> merge request (target - ***target_branch***)

As I understand my ***new_branch*** isn't created from ***target_branch*** because firstly I made push from ***new_branch*** and only then I pushed ***target_branch*** (just forgot it).

So help me please do properly the next:

I'm going to work in ***target_branch*** with my friend, and we will create our branches from it.

I need now make my ***new_branch*** to be created from ***target_branch*** and delete old ***new_branch*** (that, I suppose, now seems to be created from master not from target_branch).

How can I do this properly (for Git history)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - why can't you just do what's in your question title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `new_branch` checked out from `target_branch` (or `master` you can use same method):

```
git checkout target_branch
git cherry-pick target_branch..new_branch
git branch -f new_branch
git checkout new_branch
```

**Note:**

-If there has cherry-pick conflicts, you can modify and save the conflict files, then use `git add .` and `git cherry-pick --continue`.
-If you don’t want to rebase n`ew_branch` on the top of `target_branch`, you can use `git checkout <an history commit of target_branch>`, and then use above commands to rebase `new_branch`. As below graphs, if you use git checkout B, and after above commands, the branches will look like:

```
# Original branch structure

    A---B---C target_branch

    D---E---F new_branch

# After rebase new_branch from commit B

    A---B---C target_branch
         \
          D'---E'---F' new_branch
```

Comment: and what about Merge request?
It doesn't influence on it?

Comment: As you said, `new_branch` is not checkout from `target_branch`, and you need to make `new_branch` to checkout from `target_branch`, so you need to rebase and then merge if you want.

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve your issue, Go through below steps :

1. git checkout ***target_branch***
2. git merge ***new_branch***
3. git push origin ***target_branch***

You are now at ***target_branch***, Let's Delete Old Branch : ***new_branch***

4. git branch -D ***new_branch***
5. git branch ***new_branch***

Now you & your friend can make new branches from ***target_branch*** & work on ***new_branch***