# git checkout all files from existing branch to new branch

Tags: git

I have a branch called Branch1.

I want to copy all the files/folders in this branch to newly created branch say Branch2

Please don't ask "What have you tried so far?".

I can't try and lose my data playing around.

I googled and she was telling below, which I got confused with `target_branch` and `new_branch`.

[Git workflow: Merge existing branch to new branch and delete old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043773/git-workflow-merge-existing-branch-to-new-branch-and-delete-old-one)

Kindly suggest with detailed steps

Comment: Are you somehow unable to take a copy of your files, just in case something bad happens?

Comment: First of all i want to know if i ask a genuine clear question, why the F i get -1 for the questions, its totally discouraging

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood branching:

By default, you are on the `master` **branch**, so you are already using branches, but you didn't know it. A branch is simply a "bookmark" for commit, not a new "directory".

If you are creating a new branch, it will point to the same commit where are you right now (usually HEAD of `master`). By checking out this new branch, none of your files will be lost.

The best way to understand is learning-by-doing: create a new repository and try it out.

See Pro Git book for details:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#_create_new_branch

> What happens if you create a new branch?

Well, doing so creates a new pointer for you to move around.

It does nothing more, but adds a "bookmark" called "Branch2", the files remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b new_branch old_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `git checkout -b new_branch` will keep your local changes, moving them to the new branch.

Comment: if im in branch1> if i git checkout -b branch2, the files will just move from branch1 to 2 with latest changes ?

Comment: yeah, they will.

Comment: WIll this move the files which are 'yet to be committed/added' ? or moves files once all files are committed?

Comment: Committed files can't be changed. This works for not yet committed changes. Also if you want to have the committed changes you can branch from the branch to which you committed the changes.

Comment: Can u please tell how to get all the files if its already committed, my intention is to copy entire files/folders/everything/a-z (committed, uncommitted, yet to be added) which are in Branch1 to Branch2

Comment: The command above will do what you want. You create a new branch from the current, taking all (committed and not committed) files.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, *target_branch* is '**Branch1**' and *new_branch* is your '**Branch2**' (according to the branches name you described in your question).

So, this is what you should do:

1 - if your changes are not committed, you can simply do this:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

This will create and checkout to a new branch and keep all your changes. also, your change will exist in old branch.

2 - If you've committed your changes:

```
> git checkout Branch2
> git cherry-pick Branch2..Branch1
> git branch -f Branch1
> git checkout Branch1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @SaJadJaf, as mentioned in prev comment of prev answer, i need uncommitted, committed, yet to be added and everything, basically the exact snapshot of the current branch to the new branch